# CKEDITOR kekule (Chemical equation plugin) not working on multiple instances on same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor. I have added a kekule plugin for writing chemical equations. It is working fine with a single instance of CKEditor in one page. However if I add multiple instances of CKEditor on the same page, then the kekule image adding function is not working.

Here is plugin in config.js file:

```
config.extraPlugins = 'kekule',
Here is full code:

<textarea class="form-control" id="question" name="question" placeholder="Question"></textarea>
 <textarea class="form-control" id="option1" name="option1" placeholder="Option1"></textarea>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(typeof CKEDITOR !== 'undefined'){
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('question', {
toolbarGroups : [{ name: 'insert', groups: [ 'insert' ] },],
extraPlugins: 'kekule',
});
```

}

```
if(typeof CKEDITOR !== 'undefined'){
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('option1', {
toolbarGroups : [{ name: 'insert', groups: [ 'insert' ] },],
extraPlugins: 'kekule',
});
```

}

Comment: Check for errors in the console. It may be a bug in the implementation of that plugin.

Comment: if I add multiple instances of ckeditor on the same page, then I am getting an error like: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'doSaveObj' of null
    at a.getObjCustomSaveMethod (kekule.min.js:1)
    at a.save (kekule.min.js:1)
    at a.doWriteData (kekule.min.js:1)
    at a.writeData (kekule.min.js:1)
    at a.<anonymous> (kekule.min.js:1)
    at a.writeData (kekule.min.js:1)
    at a.writeData (kekule.min.js:1)
    at Object.Kekule.IO.saveFormatData (kekule.min.js:1)
    at Object.Kekule.IO.saveTypedData (kekule.min.js:1)
    at Object.Kekule.IO.saveMimeData (kekule.min.js:1)

Comment: Could you also show the full example of the code you're using to instantiate the editors, just to exclude that as the source of the issue. This definitely sounds like a bug in the library which you should raise with the authors.

Comment: <script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<textarea class="form-control" id="question" name="question" placeholder="Question"></textarea>
<textarea class="form-control" id="option1" name="option1" placeholder="Option1"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('question', {
    toolbarGroups : [{ name: 'insert', groups: [ 'insert' ] },],
    extraPlugins: 'kekule',
});
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('option1', {
    toolbarGroups : [{ name: 'insert', groups: [ 'insert' ] },],
    extraPlugins: 'kekule',
});
</script>